# Как вы понимаете это задание?

Tags: python

Написать функцию, которая транспонирует заданный в качестве параметра массива типа int (т.е. меняет местами равноудаленные от концов массива элементы).

Что от меня хотят?
Как я понял:

```
O=list()
M=list()
print('Ведите кол-во столбцов')
m=int(input())
print('Заполните матрицу')
for i in range(m):
    O.append(int(input()))
print('Результат одн.матрицы')
O.reverse()
print(O)
print('Ведите кол-во cтрок')
n=int(input())
print('Введите элементы матрицы n*m')
for i in range(m):
    Z=[]
    for j in range(n):
        Z.append(int(input()))
    M.append(Z)
print('Матрица m*n')
for i in M:
    print(i)
W=list()
print('Транспонированная:')
Tran=[]
for i in range(n):
    Tran.append([])

    for j in range(m):
        el=M[j][i]
        Tran[i].append(el)
for i in Tran:
    print(i)

    
print('Если перевернуть')
for i in M:
    i.reverse()
    W.append(i)
for i in W:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Я спрашивая,что от меня хотят.Мне не нужно решение. От меня хотят транспонированную матрицу?

Comment: Почему вы спрашиваете здесь, что от вас просят? Спрашивайте это у того, кто просит. В любом случае это оффтоп

Comment: Т.е. мне нужно вести матрицу(размера m или m*n)и транспонировать её?

Comment: В тексте всë поясняется.

Comment: @Funny Sad Это значит, что строки становятся столбца и, а столбцы - строками, если коротко.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо перевернуть массив.

Пример: массив [0,1,2,3]. Надо поменять равно удалённые значения местами. То есть, поменять местами 0 и 3, 1 и 2. Если мы их меняем => получаем [3,2,1,0]. Следовательно, массив перевёрнут.

Comment: Ну, я могу и вести массив типа m*n?

Comment: @FunnySad Задание же про одномерный массив, зачем вы к матрицам цепляетесь?